# British English influenced by American English

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english, british-english, spelling

I guess Br.E. is being influenced by Am.E. very much. That probably changes British words and spelling?

People who study English in schools in Britain and America, should they strictly use British spelling and words or American spelling and words or can they mix?

I mean, suppose one needs to write a dictation in Britain. If he writes *"color"* instead of *"colour"* will it be a mistake?

If somebody is writing a composition in an American school and uses the word *"lorry"* instead of *"truck"* will it be a mistake?

I just wonder how strict are rules to use exclusively British or American spelling and words in schools, universities and e.t.c. This concerns our Russian schools and universities too.

Comment: As an American teaching American English, personally, I would not mark it wrong, but I might circle it and if the students are age-appropriate, I would let them know that this is British English.

Comment: Once of the objectives of a dictation is to check that you know how to spell all of the words: you probably be expected to spell them correctly for your current locale. A composition is a different story: it's about demonstrating an ability to communicate, and details like incorrect locale spelling might be commented upon but probably would not be penalized.

Comment: I wonder where the close votes came from. This is a learning-English kind of question and it's not broad the way I see it. It's neither off-topic nor a proofreading question.

Comment: I think age and context is very important here. If someone asked me to review something for them, I'd probably point out that "lorry" might be unclear in US English (I am a southeastern US native speaker). If I just encountered it in an article, I wouldn't be offended. If my daughter said it, I would gently correct her. I watch a fair amount of UK tv, but I'm not 100% clear on what a lorry is; I know it's roughly the same as what we call a "truck", but I know they call some vehicles "trucks" also, so I'm not sure if a lorry is a big truck, a small truck, or just a synonym or what.

Comment: And if someone with a "foreign" accent said "lorry", I would just assume he had been taught English in a UK or mixed environment and wouldn't think about it again. Unless he then mentioned the "first floor", then I would probably need a clarification.

Comment: A Brit once debated a Yank concerning the rivalry between British and American English. The Brit laid out the reach of British forms, thanks to the British Empire and the BBC, and that they would thus serve better as an international standard. As the tongue originated in England, further, surely the forms of the mother country should take precedence. He concluded noting that even in the U.S., a crisp RP was taken as a mark of culture and sophistication. The Yank replied that he was unaware that any rivalry existed.

Comment: @SovereignSun I think the question is too broad because the degree to which any particular use of language is accepted or not is highly localized. It depends on the parties, their relationship, the medium, and so forth. My Sri Lankan co-worker's American accounting professor didn't have any problem with his British spellings of words, but his American marketing professor always marked him down for them, and for good reason— introducing distracting elements like foreign spellings does not improve your communication in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a student at an American school who occasionally uses British spellings (mostly by mistake; i've been trying to quash the habit in response to exactly what you're asking about).  I have been marked down on numerous occasions for British spellings.  I don't think this is because the teachers are trying to discourage the regional spellings but rather because the teacher might not recognise the spelling as valid at all and instead mark it as a total misspelling.

In cases of totally different words, like truck over lorry, the teachers are probably more likely to realise it's a regional difference, and are therefore less likely to mark off for it... though they might be confused as to why you'd chosen that word.

Comment: I try to use American spelling over that of British English and therefore am often corrected by native speakers from Britain. Once I was doing a test I had this problem with using "got" instead of "have got" and this made me realize that actually most people avoid American spelling, words and grammar.